# How to do to have a generic Entity for SQL audit tables with JPA or Hibernate?

Tags: generics, jpa, entity, reverse-engineering, generic-programming

I want to show all datas of my audit tables in a jsf page from SQL server.
I dont khnow how to do for this ?
I have to khnow the fieled of every audit table in the database to create a Entity class , or there a generic Entity whitch can get every audit table ?

Thanx in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found that:

```
AuditReader.getAuditReader()
    .createQuery()
    .forRevisionsOfEntity(EntityClass.class, false, true)
    .getResultList();
```

to get All data of an Entity X in the Audit Table